# CoolerMaster CPU cooler and case fans are not synced

Tags: cpu, motherboard, fan, cooling

I have recently purchased the following combination of products for my PC:

This CPU [cooler](https://www.overclockers.co.uk/cooler-master-masterliquid-ml240r-addressable-rgb-cpu-cooler-240mnm-hs-07v-cm.html)

3x [these fans](https://www.overclockers.co.uk/cooler-master-masterfan-pro-120mm-ap-rgb-fan-fg-02c-cm.html)

And this is my [motherboard](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Asus-Z170-Pro-Gaming-Motherboard/dp/B0126R3QPA).

The 3x separate fans are plugged into the control box, but they are only capable of blue (they can't do RGB or red) and they are not synced up with the lights on the cooler and radiator fans.

All fans spin on startup. I am looking to sync up all the lights on these fans and control them through the control box.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: You are attempting to mix Cooler Master RGB controllers/lights and ASUS RGB controllers/lights.  There really isn't a standard when it comes to RGB controllers.  In order to get them all synced up, the same controller would have to be controlling all of them.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure I understand fully your answer. I have no RGB header on my Motherboard. All fans (case/cooler/and radiator) are all going into the controller that came with the Cooler.

Comment: @CBreeze , please edit your question, reducing the number of words.  Please make it clear if you are asking about lights or fans.

Comment: @CBreeze - My comment cannot be considered an answer.  I was just pointing out you are attempting to synchronize RBG lights with the motherboard and the cooler which are different manufacturers and that RBG controllers follow no specific standard.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage I hope that is clearer?